# java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.intuit.ipp.data.ItemTypeEnum

Tags: maven, mule, intuit-partner-platform, quickbooks-online

I am trying to use quickbooks-online connector in mule project using maven. I am getting following error when I am running the mule application.

```
    ERROR 2015-03-11 16:10:05,108 [main] org.mule.module.launcher.application.DefaultMuleApplication: null
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.intuit.ipp.data.ItemTypeEnum
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:366)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:355)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:354)
    at org.mule.module.launcher.FineGrainedControlClassLoader.findClass(FineGrainedControlClassLoader.java:175)
    at org.mule.module.launcher.MuleApplicationClassLoader.findClass(MuleApplicationClassLoader.java:134)
    at org.mule.module.launcher.FineGrainedControlClassLoader.loadClass(FineGrainedControlClassLoader.java:119)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:356)
    at com.intuit.ipp.data.transformers.ItemTypeEnumEnumTransformer.<init>(ItemTypeEnumEnumTransformer.java:21)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:525)
    at org.mule.util.ClassUtils.instanciateClass(ClassUtils.java:408)
    at org.mule.util.ClassUtils.instanciateClass(ClassUtils.java:443)
    at org.mule.util.ClassUtils.instanciateClass(ClassUtils.java:415)
    at org.mule.config.bootstrap.SimpleRegistryBootstrap.registerObject(SimpleRegistryBootstrap.java:402)
    at org.mule.config.bootstrap.SimpleRegistryBootstrap.registerObjects(SimpleRegistryBootstrap.java:357)
    at org.mule.config.bootstrap.SimpleRegistryBootstrap.initialise(SimpleRegistryBootstrap.java:218)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:601)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.invokeCustomInitMethod(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1639)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.invokeInitMethods(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1580)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1510)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:521)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:458)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:293)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:223)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:290)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:191)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:633)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:932)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:479)
    at org.mule.config.spring.SpringRegistry.doInitialise(SpringRegistry.java:86)
    at org.mule.registry.AbstractRegistry.initialise(AbstractRegistry.java:105)
    at org.mule.config.spring.SpringXmlConfigurationBuilder.createSpringRegistry(SpringXmlConfigurationBuilder.java:135)
    at org.mule.config.spring.SpringXmlConfigurationBuilder.doConfigure(SpringXmlConfigurationBuilder.java:90)
    at org.mule.config.builders.AbstractConfigurationBuilder.configure(AbstractConfigurationBuilder.java:43)
    at org.mule.config.builders.AbstractResourceConfigurationBuilder.configure(AbstractResourceConfigurationBuilder.java:69)
    at org.mule.config.builders.AutoConfigurationBuilder.autoConfigure(AutoConfigurationBuilder.java:101)
    at org.mule.config.builders.AutoConfigurationBuilder.doConfigure(AutoConfigurationBuilder.java:52)
    at org.mule.config.builders.AbstractConfigurationBuilder.configure(AbstractConfigurationBuilder.java:43)
    at org.mule.config.builders.AbstractResourceConfigurationBuilder.configure(AbstractResourceConfigurationBuilder.java:69)
    at org.mule.context.DefaultMuleContextFactory$1.configure(DefaultMuleContextFactory.java:84)
    at org.mule.context.DefaultMuleContextFactory.doCreateMuleContext(DefaultMuleContextFactory.java:217)
    at org.mule.context.DefaultMuleContextFactory.createMuleContext(DefaultMuleContextFactory.java:76)
    at org.mule.module.launcher.application.DefaultMuleApplication.init(DefaultMuleApplication.java:187)
    at org.mule.module.launcher.artifact.ArtifactWrapper$2.execute(ArtifactWrapper.java:62)
    at org.mule.module.launcher.artifact.ArtifactWrapper.executeWithinArtifactClassLoader(ArtifactWrapper.java:129)
    at org.mule.module.launcher.artifact.ArtifactWrapper.init(ArtifactWrapper.java:57)
    at org.mule.module.launcher.DefaultArtifactDeployer.deploy(DefaultArtifactDeployer.java:25)
    at org.mule.module.launcher.DefaultArchiveDeployer.guardedDeploy(DefaultArchiveDeployer.java:310)
    at org.mule.module.launcher.DefaultArchiveDeployer.deployArtifact(DefaultArchiveDeployer.java:330)
    at org.mule.module.launcher.DefaultArchiveDeployer.deployExplodedApp(DefaultArchiveDeployer.java:297)
    at org.mule.module.launcher.DefaultArchiveDeployer.deployExplodedArtifact(DefaultArchiveDeployer.java:108)
    at org.mule.module.launcher.DeploymentDirectoryWatcher.deployExplodedApps(DeploymentDirectoryWatcher.java:290)
    at org.mule.module.launcher.DeploymentDirectoryWatcher.start(DeploymentDirectoryWatcher.java:151)
    at org.mule.module.launcher.MuleDeploymentService.start(MuleDeploymentService.java:99)
    at org.mule.module.launcher.MuleContainer.start(MuleContainer.java:152)
    at org.mule.tooling.server.application.ApplicationDeployer.main(ApplicationDeployer.java:15)
INFO  2015-03-11 16:10:05,117 [main] org.mule.module.launcher.application.DefaultMuleApplication: App 'exampleqb' never started, nothing to dispose of
ERROR 2015-03-11 16:10:05,160 [main] org.mule.module.launcher.DefaultArchiveDeployer: 
++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++
+ Failed to deploy artifact 'exampleqb', see below         +
++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++
org.mule.module.launcher.DeploymentInitException: ClassNotFoundException: com.intuit.ipp.data.ItemTypeEnum
    at org.mule.module.launcher.application.DefaultMuleApplication.init(DefaultMuleApplication.java:196)
    at org.mule.module.launcher.artifact.ArtifactWrapper$2.execute(ArtifactWrapper.java:62)
    at org.mule.module.launcher.artifact.ArtifactWrapper.executeWithinArtifactClassLoader(ArtifactWrapper.java:129)
    at org.mule.module.launcher.artifact.ArtifactWrapper.init(ArtifactWrapper.java:57)
    at org.mule.module.launcher.DefaultArtifactDeployer.deploy(DefaultArtifactDeployer.java:25)
    at org.mule.module.launcher.DefaultArchiveDeployer.guardedDeploy(DefaultArchiveDeployer.java:310)
    at org.mule.module.launcher.DefaultArchiveDeployer.deployArtifact(DefaultArchiveDeployer.java:330)
    at org.mule.module.launcher.DefaultArchiveDeployer.deployExplodedApp(DefaultArchiveDeployer.java:297)
    at org.mule.module.launcher.DefaultArchiveDeployer.deployExplodedArtifact(DefaultArchiveDeployer.java:108)
    at org.mule.module.launcher.DeploymentDirectoryWatcher.deployExplodedApps(DeploymentDirectoryWatcher.java:290)
    at org.mule.module.launcher.DeploymentDirectoryWatcher.start(DeploymentDirectoryWatcher.java:151)
    at org.mule.module.launcher.MuleDeploymentService.start(MuleDeploymentService.java:99)
    at org.mule.module.launcher.MuleContainer.start(MuleContainer.java:152)
    at org.mule.tooling.server.application.ApplicationDeployer.main(ApplicationDeployer.java:15)
Caused by: org.mule.api.config.ConfigurationException: Error creating bean with name '_muleSimpleRegistryBootstrap' defined in URL [jar:file:/D:/MULE/AnypointStudio/plugins/org.mule.tooling.server.3.5.2.ee_4.1.0.201410031231/mule/lib/mule/mule-module-spring-config-3.5.2.jar!/registry-bootstrap-mule-config.xml]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is org.mule.api.lifecycle.InitialisationException: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/intuit/ipp/data/ItemTypeEnum (org.mule.api.lifecycle.InitialisationException) (org.mule.api.config.ConfigurationException)
    at org.mule.config.builders.AbstractConfigurationBuilder.configure(AbstractConfigurationBuilder.java:49)
    at org.mule.config.builders.AbstractResourceConfigurationBuilder.configure(AbstractResourceConfigurationBuilder.java:69)
    at org.mule.context.DefaultMuleContextFactory$1.configure(DefaultMuleContextFactory.java:84)
    at org.mule.context.DefaultMuleContextFactory.doCreateMuleContext(DefaultMuleContextFactory.java:217)
    at org.mule.context.DefaultMuleContextFactory.createMuleContext(DefaultMuleContextFactory.java:76)
    at org.mule.module.launcher.application.DefaultMuleApplication.init(DefaultMuleApplication.java:187)
    ... 13 more
```

I'm new to this connector and Maven. What is ItemTypeEnum? 
How can I solve this error?
Thanks for help in advance.!!

Following is my mule flow:

```
<quickbooks:config name="Quickbooks_Online" consumerKey="key" consumerSecret="secret" objectStore-ref="_defaultInMemoryObjectStore" doc:name="Quickbooks Online" baseUri="https://sandbox-quickbooks.api.intuit.com/v3/company"/>
<flow name="Authorize" doc:name="Authorize">
    <!-- INBOUND ENDPOINT -->
    <http:inbound-endpoint exchange-pattern="request-response" host="localhost" port="8081" doc:name="HTTP"/>
    <quickbooks:auth-user config-ref="Quickbooks_Online" accessTokenUrl="https://oauth.intuit.com/oauth/v1/get_access_token" authorizationUrl="https://appcenter.intuit.com/Connect/Begin" callbackUrl="http://localhost:8090" requestTokenId="#[groovy:message.getSessionProperty('requestTokenIdentifier')]" requestTokenUrl="https://oauth.intuit.com/oauth/v1/get_request_token" doc:name="Quickbooks Online"/>
</flow>
 <flow name="GetAccessToken" doc:name="GetAccessToken">
        <http:inbound-endpoint exchange-pattern="one-way" host="localhost" port="8090" doc:name="HTTP"/>
        <logger message="The key value created is: #[payload]" level="INFO" doc:name="Logger"/>
        <quickbooks:get-access-token config-ref="Quickbooks_Online" doc:name="Quickbooks Online" requestTokenId="#[message.inboundProperties['userId']]" userIdentifier="#[message.inboundProperties['realmId']]" verifier="#[message.inboundProperties['oauth_verifier']]" apiUrl="https://sandbox-api.intuit.com/v3/company/"/>
        <logger message="QB: #[payload] : #[message.inboundProperties['realmId']]" level="INFO" doc:name="Logger"/>
        <flow-ref name="ListAccounts" doc:name="Flow Reference"/>
```

Comment: Seems like a dependency is missing. Is the com.intuit.ipp.data.ItemTypeEnum class in the classpath?

Comment: No. It is not. So how can i add this missing dependency?

Comment: You said you are using maven, how are you referencing the quickbooks-online connector. Also, check the app file generated to see if the connector is there.

Answer (score 0):

'Type' attribute of Item entity is defined as String. 
Ref - https://developer.intuit.com/docs/0025_quickbooksapi/0050_data_services/030_entity_services_reference/item

It can contain either 'Service' or 'Inventory'.

Can you share the usecase on why you are suing ItemTypeEnum?

Comment: I am building a mule application using quickbooks-oline connector.

Answer (score 0):

I tried to add the missing dependencies i.e., ipp-v3-java-devkit and ipp-v3-java.data the following way and it worked.

```
1. mvn install:install-file 
   -DgroupId=com.intuit.code.devkit.v3 
   -DartifactId=ipp-v3-java-devkit 
   -Dversion=2.3.2 
   -Dpackaging=jar -Dfile=C:/Users/user/Documents/QBMavenJar/ipp-v3-java-data-2.3.2.jar

2. <repository>
   <id>my-local-repo</id>
   <url>file:///home/user/.m2/repository/com/intuit/code/devkit/v3/ipp-v3-java-devkit/2.3.2/ipp-v3-java-devkit-2.3.2.jar</url>
   </repository>

3. <dependency>
   <groupId>com.intuit.code.devkit.v3</groupId>
   <artifactId>ipp-v3-java-devkit</artifactId>
   <version>2.3.2</version>
   </dependency>
```

Performed above steps for both the dependencies.